# numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append' - error comes up when creating stack using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, stack

### I want to create a stack using numpy

I tried following code but "numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append' " this error comes
I tried replace the append with other attributes , but any of those methods didnt work for me .
can someone run the codes in your pc and suggest me a way to fix this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Banchi\Desktop\numpy\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    myStack.push(11)
  File "C:\Users\Banchi\Desktop\numpy\stackf.py", line 8, in push
    return self.Stack.append(data)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

---

### stackf.py

```
import numpy as np

class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Stack =np.array([])

    def push(self,data):
            return self.Stack.append(data)
            print("stack overfolow")

    def pop(self):
        if len(self.Stack)==0:
            print("stack underflow")
        else:
            return self.Stack.pop()
    def __len(self):
        return len(self.Stack)

    def top(self):
        if len(self.Stack)==0:
            print("stack under flow")
        else:
            return self.Stack[len(self.Stack)-1]

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self.Stack) == 0

    def is_full(self):
        return len(self.Stack) == self.limit


    def size(self):
        return len(self.Stack)
```

---

### main.py

```
from stackf import Stack
myStack = Stack()
myStack.push(11)
myStack.push(11)
myStack.push(11)
myStack.push(11)
print(myStack.size())
myStack.push(10)
myStack.push(20)
myStack.push(30)

print(myStack)
```

Comment: A list has an in-place `append` method.  A numpy array does not!  You have skipped basic documentation for python and numpy.  There is a `np.append` function, but I discourage its use (or misuse)

Comment: When you get an `AttributeError`, check 2 things.  The type of the object - is it what you expect?  Is `self.Stack` supposed to be an array?  And check the method (or other attribute).  This may require searching the class's documentation.  Don't assume that because one class implements a method that other (similar) ones do as well.  Check the documentation before you ask SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your class e.g. as:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self, limit : int = 0):
        self.arr = np.array([])
        self.limit = limit

    def is_empty(self) -> bool:
        return self.size() == 0

    def pop(self):
        n = self.size() - 1
        if n < 0:
            raise Exception('pop - Stack is empty')
        rv = self.arr[n]
        self.arr = np.delete(self.arr, n)
        return rv

    def push(self, data):
        if self.limit > 0 and self.limit == self.size():
            raise Exception('push - Limit exceeded')
        self.arr = np.append(self.arr, data)

    def size(self) -> int:
        return self.arr.size

    def top(self):
        if self.size() == 0:
            raise Exception('top - stack underflow')
        return self.arr[-1]

    def __str__(self):
        return np.array_str(self.arr)
```

Note that I added some functionality concerning the *limit*, but the
default value of *limit* is **0**, meaning "no limit".

Since the class contains `size()` method, there is no need to repeat
just the same code in `__len()` method.

I added also some exceptions instead of printing an error message.

`__str__` method is added to get any meaningful result when you *print*
a *Stack* instance.

Then, if you run your main code, the result is:

```
4
[11. 11. 11. 11. 10. 20. 30.]
```

But if you create your *Stack* instance e.g. as `myStack = Stack(3)`
(with the limit set to a non-zero value), then at some point you
will get *Exception: push - Limit exceeded*.

Comment: very well understood. Thank you so much mate .. Bravo ..